# Is it possible to create a react WebApp for iPad without react-native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, ipad, uiwebview

I want to build a React webapp to be used on an iPad.

Basically I just want to click on the HomeScreen of my WebApp and it should open in fullscreen mode.

But i am not sure if its possible to do that on a iPad, when I was searching for this topic I only found stuff for react-native. Yet I want to know if it’s possible to do w/ plain react.

Someone who can tell if this possible and if yes, how I should go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to keep this on the web, you could create a Progressive Web App using a Service Worker. There is a great general tutorial from Google at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/. PWA's can have a save to home screen option, where your web app is stored on the users home screen like an app and is viewed full screen.

Or a specific React implementation from Addy Osmani is available here - https://medium.com/@addyosmani/progressive-web-apps-with-react-js-part-i-introduction-50679aef2b12.

I created a PWA for a university project before I graduated and it was great fun. Browsers are starting to adopt this more, with other features features being introduced such as Background Sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app that simply renders standard HTML/JS as though the user where in a browser with something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). The basic idea is to put an app icon on your mobile device that links to a regular website. This is what you would have to do to use React on a mobile device as though it were an app. Alternatively, people could just visit your React site through a browser.

React Native transpiles to Android and iOS code (Java and Swift), which you then compile into 2 native apps. One for iOS and one for Android. It looks and acts a lot like ReactJS, but it's a different beast and most regular React apps will not be portable to React Native without significant alterations.